# Boost audio performance on old Windows 7 laptop

Tags: computer

I've recently dug out some tracks I produced on the tracker Jeskola Buzz. I have installed the latest version of the software from Jeskola.net on an old Sony Vaio PCG-7164M. However,  I now remember back to the days I used to make the track, that I needed an upgraded sound card. At the time I had a desktop with an M-audio card in it. But now I am using this laptop, I am not sure what I need. Specifically what happens is that anything that starts to need more resources from the computer in Jeskola Buzz, such as more tracks, more complicated sounds, more effects and generators I start to hear clicks, pops and stutters.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a Memory Problem, the pops and clicks etc. are memory overruns.
Turning up your Buffer Size/ Sample Rate or deactivating some Costy effects while producing because when you render/export your audio file these clicks and pops will not be happening anymore.

If ur PC has a very low ram to use (4 or maybe 8 gigs) having 30+ effects is mostly not handable.
Stuff like the Apollo Twin (whole apollo series) are good examples how extern hardware could delete this problem as it will let processing be happening in the interface itself and not your pc/daw.

Summary:
Turn up your Buffer Size and/or Sample Rate.
Deactive some other effects while working on something, as in the end putting it together and rendering it will Sound fine.
Upgrade ur RAM.
Upgrade / Buy a processing audio interface / mixer.

Greets

Edit : Before i forget it, soundcards arent normaly happening anymore. I asked multiple Producers/ Technicians on their opinion. a USB interface will basicly work as a extern sound card and handle it. USB will transfer lossless so a standart onboard/ motherboard soundcard will mostly/(anything 2015+) always be sufficent.

Comment: great information thanks!